# Why isn't mySql recorgnizing the column in the table field list?

Tags: mysql

Why is mySql throwing the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'this.revenue' in table field list"? Please see the attached image of the database table structure and the SQL statement below.
[image]

By this query I'm trying to compare revenue from last year with the revenue this year.

```
SELECT this.revenue as current_amount , 
this.weekno, 
history.revenue AS past_amount
FROM (SELECT YEAR(`inserted_at`) AS `year`
    , WEEKOFYEAR(`inserted_at`) AS weekno
    , SUM(revenue) AS amount
  FROM class_customer_activity
  WHERE YEAR(`inserted_at`) = YEAR(NOW())
  GROUP BY YEAR(`inserted_at`), WEEKOFYEAR(`inserted_at`)) AS this
JOIN (SELECT YEAR(`inserted_at`) AS `year`
    , WEEKOFYEAR(`inserted_at`) AS weekno
    , SUM(revenue) AS amount
  FROM class_customer_activity
  WHERE YEAR(`inserted_at`) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
  GROUP BY YEAR(`inserted_at`), WEEKOFYEAR(`inserted_at`)) AS history
ON this.weekno = history.weekno ;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the revenue column isn't part of the select in the derived tables; it only appears as an aggregate `sum(revenue)` which is aliased as `amount`.

You need to refer to it as `this.amount` (and `history.amount`)

<strike>Also, the last join should most likely include the `year` column as well or you'll get `weekno` from different years joined together.</strike>

I realized the paragraph above isn't a problem currently as you only select from two different years. It might be a good practice to qualify the join with the year anyway for clarity and to prevent future problems is you diced to include more years in the query.

Comment: @objellandob please revisit your questions and award the green tick to the best / most helpful answers that resolve your issues.  Volunteers who give the best answers eventually gain enough rep points to earn privileges which they can use to better serve the community.  You can greatly help this community by upvoting and accepting great answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `ALIAS` `revenue` instead of `amount` on the `SUB SELECT` on the `FROM`.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(`inserted_at`) AS `year`,
    WEEKOFYEAR(`inserted_at`) AS weekno,
    SUM(revenue) AS revenue
```

Alternative, you could change to `this.amount` and `history.amount` in the main `SELECT`

```
SELECT 
    this.amount as current_amount, 
    this.weekno, 
    history.amount AS past_amount
```